# JavaScript Date set not working as expected. How to resolve?

Tags: javascript

My code returning Sat

> Jan 25 2020 15:06:45 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

anyone, please tell me why is it not working as my expectation?

Code:

```js
let date1 = new Date(2019, 12, 25);
console.log(date1);
```

Comment: Javascript does not have months starting from 1 through 12 instead they start from 0 and end with 11. For your case you should use 11 for December.

Comment: You should check the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript, the month of a `Date` is similar to an index of an array, in the aspect that it starts from 0 and goes to 12.

So you should do:

```js
let date1 = new Date(2019, 11, 25);
console.log(date1);
```

Keep in mind that `console.log(date)` will return the date in `UTC` format so it might be off by a few hours (which might also change the date by 1), do `console.log(date.toString())` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use format like this,

```
let date1 = new Date("2019-12-25");
console.log(date1);
```

And you will get a response like this,

```
Wed Dec 25 2019 06:00:00 GMT+0600
```